# mysql-connector-j 8.0 - setting timezone for SqlTimestampValueFactory?

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

I have 10~ mysql tables with 20~ `DATETIME` fields. and Trying to migrate tables from mysql to google bigquery.

In the process I happened to use mysql-connector-j 8.0.x, and as far as I know mysql `DATETIME` does not know about timezone. and bigquery's `TIMESTAMP` saves timestamp as UTC.

So I should change mysql `DATETIME` with timezone information.

I guess it would be handled by `SqlTimestampValueFactory`. 
Is my guess is correct? and if it is true how can I customize `tz` of `SqlTimestampValueFactory`?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize tz value for SqlTimestampValueFactory by setting `serverTimezone` property.

Even if mysql `DATETIME` datetype has no timezone information. timezone assumption is done by server variable `time_zone`. And `mysql-connector-j` handles conversion through `TimestampValueFactory` with `ServerSession.getDefaultTimezone()`.

So in my case `serverTimezone` property setting was enough.

TL;DR

SqlTimestampValueFactory is initialized at ResultSetImpl.

```
# com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl#ResultSetImpl
this.defaultTimestampValueFactory = 
   decorateDateTimeValueFactory(
      new SqlTimestampValueFactory(
          this.session.getServerSession().getDefaultTimeZone()),
          this.zeroDateTimeBehavior);
```

NativeProtocol is initializing defaultTimeZone

```
String canonicalTimezone = getPropertySet().getStringReadableProperty(PropertyDefinitions.PNAME_serverTimezone).getValue();
...
...
if (canonicalTimezone != null && canonicalTimezone.length() > 0) {
        this.serverSession.setServerTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(canonicalTimezone));
...
```